# Upgrade from Rails 2.3.2 Ruby 1.8.6 to Rails 2.3.5 Ruby 1.8.7 uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, upgrade, compatibility

I have tried to upgrade my application from Rails 2.3.2 to Rails 2.3.5 on a machine that is running Ruby 1.8.7.  My old machine where the application was working was running Ruby 1.8.6.

When I try to startup I get the following error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:55: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:49:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:49:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support.rb:56
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:49:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:49:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:1
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:49:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:49:in `require'
    from script/server:3
```

Being a mega newbie I have been seaching the web trying to figure this all out. I can't seem to get it to work.

Anyone have a magic bullet. Either for my code or me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just dealt with this issue today. my ruby version is 1.8.7. my app is in rails 2.3.8 and i installed rubygems 1.3.6. This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this have been answered before.

[Uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176782/uninitialized-constant-activesupportdependenciesmutex-nameerror)

It is an incompatibility of Rails and rubygems. Try reinstalling rubygems or upgrade to the latest version of Rails.