# Dependencies Problem RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dependencies, rvm

I recently installed RoR on Ubuntu 10 using RVM and everything seemed to be working fine but when I try to create a simple app to see if everything is working properly I get the fallowing error:

```
josethernandezc@josethernandezc:~$ rails sample_app  

/home/josethernandezc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:55: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)
```

Ruby: 1.8.7
Gem: 1.6.2
Rails: 2.3.5

```
josethernandezc@josethernandezc:~$ rvm info

ruby-1.8.7-p334:

system:
  uname:       "Linux josethernandezc 2.6.35-28-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 1 14:40:58 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux"
bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)"
zsh:         " => not installed"

rvm:
version:      "rvm 1.5.2 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

ruby:
interpreter:  "ruby"
version:      "1.8.7"
date:         "2011-02-18"
platform:     "i686-linux"
patchlevel:   "2011-02-18 patchlevel 334"
full_version: "ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-linux]"

homes:
gem:          "/home/josethernandezc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334"
ruby:         "/home/josethernandezc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334"

binaries:
ruby:         "/home/josethernandezc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/ruby"
irb:          "/home/josethernandezc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/irb"
gem:          "/home/josethernandezc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/gem"
rake:         "/home/josethernandezc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin/rake"

environment:
PATH:         "/home/josethernandezc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin:/home/josethernandezc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@global/bin:/home/josethernandezc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin:/home/josethernandezc/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
GEM_HOME:     "/home/josethernandezc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334"
GEM_PATH:     "/home/josethernandezc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334:/home/josethernandezc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@global"
MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/josethernandezc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334"
IRBRC:        "/home/josethernandezc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/.irbrc"
RUBYOPT:      ""
gemset:       ""
```

Comment: I tried to google the error message but I wasn't able to get much information about the error

Comment: Add the output of `rvm info` to your question please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176782/uninitialized-constant-activesupportdependenciesmutex-nameerror)

Comment: This is the output for rvm info...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ubuntu 10.10 is not supporting the activesupport gems.try to install activesupport gem once again, If still the problem persist refer this blog http://railsappmadeasy.blogspot.com/ here I mentioned the complete steps to install ROR on ubuntu 10.10.Hope this will help you.

Comment: That doesn't mention RVM in any way, which the OP is using.

Comment: you can use RVM as well ones it installs the default Ruby on Rails on your Ubuntu,Follow the steps for RVM from http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by upgrading rails

```
gem install rails --version 4.2.8

gem install rails --version [latest version 5.1.1]
```

Comment: if you satisfy with my ans then make it correct and vote up