# Unable to migrate Ruby gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am pretty new to rails. Trying to rake/migrate to a new server. Here is the error I am getting.

```
[~/rails_apps/baseforesight/config]# rake db:migrate --trace(in 
/home/i****\/rails_apps\/baseforesight)
rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)rake aborted!
uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing'
/home/iftftv/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:55
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/iftftv/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support.rb:56
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/iftftv/ruby/gems/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/misc.rake:18
/home/iftftv/ruby/gems/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4:in `load'
/home/iftftv/ruby/gems/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4
/home/iftftv/ruby/gems/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4:in `each'
/home/iftftv/ruby/gems/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/home/iftftv/rails_apps/baseforesight/Rakefile:10
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/li/rake/application.rb:495:in`raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `load_rakefile'
```

I need sort of a clue on where to start. Anything will be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: TheRealDK - the problem you are experiencing is not specific to the db:migrate task - the Rails framework isn't loading. It could be helpful to edit the question title to reflect that, perhaps including the key part of the error message: "uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex".

Answer (score 2):

[According to this Stack Overflow answer, you need to upgrade Rails to 2.3.11.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176782/uninitialized-constant-activesupportdependenciesmutex-nameerror)

This should be a fairly painless upgrade if my one upgrade experience was normal.