# Issue with rake gem:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using

> Rails 2.3.5, Ruby 1.8.7

I am getting the follow error after running the following command. Any ideas?

```
$ rake gem:install

$ rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
$ rake aborted!


$ rake gem:install --trace

rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:55
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support.rb:56
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/misc.rake:18
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4:in `load'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4:in `each'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/rails.rb:4
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/P/Dev/loginform/unobtrusive-login/Rakefile:10
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the first lines in your `Rakefile`. Change:

```
require 'rake/rdoctask'
```

To:

```
require 'rdoc/task'
```

**Edit**:

It looks like you have a Rubygems incompatibility issue, like James suspects. You need to upgrade your Rails version, or downgrade your gem version.

You can change to any gem version with:

```
gem update --system x.y.z
```

See more about your problem with

```
uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex
```

Here:
[Uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176782/uninitialized-constant-activesupportdependenciesmutex-nameerror)

Comment: I get: no such file to load -- rdoc/task

Answer (score 2):

I am using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.8 and getting the very same error. So I changed my RubyGems version to 1.5.3 and the issue solved. So what you need to do is to write this command:
"gem update --system 1.5.3"
It will update your ruby gems version to 1.5.3 which is fully working with rails 2.3.8.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of rubygems do you have? To use 2.3.5 you might need to use rubygems that <= 1.4 and rake 0.8.7.