# "uninitialized constant Etc" when running Ruby application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, fedora

A few applications on my server relying on **Ruby** and **Ruby On Rails** seem to have stopped working. Or atleast partially so. I managed to get the web gui of the application in question to start functioning again by reinstalling different part of Ruby. But I most likley broke something else in the process.

I have managed to track it down using some tests and it seems like **Etc** is somehow not found by the program when it runs.

I tested by

```
ruby -e 'puts Etc.getpwnam("apache").uid'
```

and got

> uninitialized constant Etc

If I instead tested

```
ruby -r etc -e 'puts Etc.getpwnam("apache").uid'
```

I get the correct answer

> 48

This is running on an **Amahi6** server (running **Fedora Core 14 64bit**).

Example on the code in question in the actual application that fails is

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# Amahi Home Server
# Copyright (C) 2007-2010 Amahi
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
# modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License v3
# (29 June 2007), as published in the COPYING file.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# file COPYING for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public
# License along with this program; if not, write to the Amahi
# team at http://www.amahi.org/ under "Contact Us."

require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/boot'
#require 'commands/runner'
require 'optparse'

# switch to apache:users first
uid = Etc.getpwnam("apache").uid
gid = Etc.getgrnam("users").gid
Process.gid = gid
Process.egid = gid
Process.uid = uid
Process.euid = uid
...
```

this fails with the same

> uninitialized constant Etc

Clarification: **I have NOT changed this code at all and it has worked in it's current state before**

What could it be that I have messed up? :)

UPDATE:
Ruby installed now is version **1.8.7**

UPDATE 2:

If I try to manually add a **require** for **rubygems** and **etc** it fails, but complains about another package. So I think there is something fundamentally messed up with the core of my ruby.

> /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:55:
>   uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)
>           from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
>   `gem_original_require'
>           from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
>           from
>   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support.rb:56
>           from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
>   `gem_original_require'
>           from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
>           from
>   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record.rb:25
>           from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
>   `gem_original_require'
>           from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
>           from /var/hda/platform/html/script/install-app:70

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "reinstalling different part of Ruby"? And it would help if you would put the ruby version as well (ruby -v).

Comment: It was quite a bit of time ago so a bit blurry I'm afraid. But I think I reinstalled ruby and libs using yum. So **yum reinstall ruby** and **yum reinstall ruby-libs**. Maybe something with the gems to but I don't think so.

Comment: You can try to reinstall the gems required with "rake gems:install" (in the directory where the rails app is). I'm afraid your best bet is to reinstall Amahi as the install script looks quite complicated.

Comment: That would suck :)... I have tons of stuf finstalled... hehe... When trying to run the rake command I also get an error: **uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex**

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176782/uninitialized-constant-activesupportdependenciesmutex-nameerror, it should allow you to go ahead.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'd be interested in knowing the root cause.

Comment: Didn't have time to look at it but last night I sat down to fix it. Ended up being that the versions of rails and gems were to new. Downgraded to **gems 1.3.7** and **rails 2.3.8**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up being that the versions of rails and gems were to new. Downgraded to **gems 1.3.7** and **rails 2.3.8**.

```
gem update --system 1.3.7

gem uninstall rails

gem install rails --version 2.3.8
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing `require 'rubygems'` and `require 'etc'` (put them below `require 'optparse'`)

Comment: But I have not changed the Amahi ruby code at all. It just stopped working. Very strange that I all of a sudden would have to go through code and add require statements that weren't needed before? It's not that there could be a conf file that tells ruby to ALWAYS include these that I might have removed or overwritten or something?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you on that one. I don't know how Amahi works. In fact, I didn't even know it existed before answering your question :-)

Answer (score 0):

remember about 'rubygems',

commandline:

```
ruby -rubygems -e 'puts Etc.getpwnam("apache").uid'
```

script:

```
require 'rubygems'
puts Etc.getpwnam("apache").uid
```