# Uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError) - How to resolve?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176782/uninitialized-constant-activesupportdependenciesmutex-nameerror)

Hey I have seen this issue a lot across the web... Anybody resolve this with any success?

My app is `RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.5' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION`

The log output

```
/Users/tjs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@rails2/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:55: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)
from /Users/tjs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
from /Users/tjs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/tjs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@rails2/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support.rb:56
from /Users/tjs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
from /Users/tjs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/tjs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@rails2/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:1
from /Users/tjs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
from /Users/tjs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from script/server:4
```

I have tried requiring thread in the environment.rb, script/sever and rakefile but that just blows up the log...

I have rvm using 1.8.7 which I think is compatible.  But I am still newer to rvm so not totally sure I have it working right.

I have 3 apps running rails 2.x and have this problem with all of them.

Comment: Also if I run gem -v it says 1.8.11 which may mean that I am using rvm wrong...

Comment: I have reviewed that question and answers, the require 'thread' doesn't work.  Should I do a rvm install 1.5.3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://ecmanaut.blogspot.com/2011/09/running-old-rails-238-with-rvm.html  followed these steps and the app works again.

thanks for all the posts

Answer (score 3):

add the "require 'thread'"statement to your  "boot.rb" file.

```
require 'thread'
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'boot')
```

Comment: I have tried that, and it does not resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

you just need use a new gemset using rbenv https://github.com/jamis/rbenv-gemset or rvm and install this one rubygems-update 1.4.2

```
gem install -v 1.4.2 rubygems-update
gem update --system 1.4.2
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that worked for me is to use rails of higher minor version by settting env:

```
export RAILS_GEM_VERSION=2.3.12
```