# Rails 2.3.5 & ruby 1.8.7 issue while creating new application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using rails 2.3.5 & ruby 1.8.7. i am getting this error while creating the new application.

```
/home/sheetal/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@rails2/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:55: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@rails2/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support.rb:56
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@rails2/gems/rails-2.3.5/bin/../lib/rails_generator.rb:28
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@rails2/gems/rails-2.3.5/bin/rails:14
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@rails2/bin/rails:23:in `load'
    from /home/sheetal/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@rails2/bin/rails:23
```

Comment: checkout the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862845/uninitialized-constant-activesupportdependenciesmutex-nameerror-how-to-r

Comment: Please please please don't create a new Rails app using a soon to be end-of-life version of both ruby and rails.

Comment: Ref:- http://ecmanaut.blogspot.in/2011/09/running-old-rails-238-with-rvm.html