# how to deploy a ruby app?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake

I'm a Ruby beginner who get a web app in Ruby which I want to start. 
I have installed Ruby Enterprise, Rails (and Unicorn, nginx).

I have in the web app root folder: Capfile, Gemfile, Gemfile.lock, Rakfeile, version, version.rb

When I execute inside this folder:
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.01/bin/rake

I get:

```
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' 
(in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.

at /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.01/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb 
rake aborted!

uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex
```

I must say this web app was working before on another setup as is.

Can someone say me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Refer here:

1. [fixing-uninitialized-constant-activesupport-dependencies-mutex-nameerror](https://makandracards.com/makandra/1051-fixing-uninitialized-constant-activesupport-dependencies-mutex-nameerror)
2. [uninitialized-constant-activesupportdependenciesmutex-nameerror - SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176782/uninitialized-constant-activesupportdependenciesmutex-nameerror)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at passenger:

http://www.modrails.com/

Its simple and straightforward, you might give it a try