# 'Rails server' <- does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails.
I was asked to make some improvements to existing project.
I downloaded it from Heroku.
It uses ruby "1.8.7", thanks to rvm I also have it for project's directory.
I managed to bundle update and bundle install.
Now I try to 'rails server' and I get error messages:

```
/home/jacek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:55: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)
  from /home/jacek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support.rb:56:in `require'
  from /home/jacek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support.rb:56
  from /home/jacek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/rails-2.3.5/bin/../lib/rails_generator.rb:28:in `require'
  from /home/jacek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/rails-2.3.5/bin/../lib/rails_generator.rb:28
  from /home/jacek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/rails-2.3.5/bin/rails:14:in `require'
  from /home/jacek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/rails-2.3.5/bin/rails:14
  from /home/jacek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/bin/rails:19:in `load'
  from /home/jacek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/bin/rails:19
  from /home/jacek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you!

Jacek

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176782/uninitialized-constant-activesupportdependenciesmutex-nameerror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple...

ruby script/server
instead of 
rails s

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo gem update --system
```

Worked for me :-) For details have a look at this [ruby forum](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1202806)

Also the link in the comment [Uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Dependencies::Mutex (NameError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176782/uninitialized-constant-activesupportdependenciesmutex-nameerror) is a good solution source.